Transforming an expression into function
I want to transform the expression a = 2 x + 1 into f=Exp[a], z=Log[x], and express the result as f[z] (my expression for a is actually more complicated than this minimal example). I did this:
f[z_] := (a // Exp) /. x -> Log[z];
f[w]
E w^2

It works except for one strange behavior: When I plot f[myDummyVariable] as a function of myDummyVariable I get the expected behavior unless myDummyVariable is x:
Show[
 Plot[f[y], {y, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]


After some research I found out that I can use the simpler
f[x_] := Evaluate[(a // Exp) /. x -> Log[x]];

which does not have this problem. Still, why the conflict when I use x as the dummy variable in my method above?

In the definition f[z_] := (a // Exp) /. x -> Log[z]; the argument z appears nowhere on the RHS. `/. x -> Log[z]^does nothing as x appears nowhere in the definition.

I am not sure what you mean. f[z] returns E z^2 as it should, so z is recognized as the variable of the function.  The function works with any dummy variable except x.

As a matter of fact, f[x] returns E x^2 but plots something else.

The Plot function has attribute HoldAll.

I have MMA version 14.1 and f[z_] := (a // Exp) /. x -> Log[z]; always returns e^a as it should, regardless of the argument.

@DanielHuber Interesting… I’m running MMA 14.0.0.0 on OS 14.6.1.

It looks like the x in Plot is not localized, and x is being set; similar to running, for example, x=3; f[anything]. Workaround is f[z_] := Module[{x}, (2 x + 1 // Exp) /. x -> Log[z]];

Your code is fraught with dangers; as you are experiencing.  Any reason why you are not defining a function of x with your expression?

In my case, the expression is the result of FindFit, which I then turn into a function.

This is because Plot, like other similar functions such as Sum or Do, localizes its variable in a manner akin to Block. We can see what's happening by tracing the evaluation of a Block at, say, x=3:
Block[{x = 3}, f[x]] // Trace

{Block[{x = 3}, f[x]], {x = 3, 3}, {{x, 3}, f[3], 
  Exp[a] /. x -> Log[3], {{a, 1 + 2 x, {{x, 3}, 2 3, 6}, 1 + 6, 7}, 
   Exp[7], E^7}, {{x, 3}, 3 -> Log[3], 3 -> Log[3]}, 
  E^7 /. 3 -> Log[3], E^7}, E^7}

Inside this Block, all instances of x evaluate to 3, including the x in the definition of a. During evaluation, Exp[a] first evaluates to Exp[2 3+1] = E^7 before /. attempts replacement (and there are clearly no 3s in that expression).
As you have found, this can be avoided by evaluating the definition. This resolves the reference to a that was present in the prior definition:
f[z_] := (a // Exp) /. x -> Log[z]; DownValues@f
f[z_] := Evaluate[(a // Exp) /. x -> Log[z]]; DownValues@f
f[z_] = (a // Exp) /. x -> Log[z]; DownValues@f

{HoldPattern[f[z_]] :> (Exp[a] /. x -> Log[z])}

{HoldPattern[f[z_]] :> E z^2}

{HoldPattern[f[z_]] :> E z^2}

